# How to find a row number given multiple column conditions in R?

Tags: r

Say for example I have the following example dataframe:

```html
gender <- c('F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M')
wage <- c(2100, 2100, 2500, 2400, 2300)
age <- c(25, 24, 29, 30, 32)

example <- data.frame(gender, wage, age)
example
```

How can I find which row has the following column criteria: F, 2100 & 24. So this answer would be row 2 and I need the answer to be **the row number**.

And #stackoverflow beginner question, how can I make sure the data frame in the stackoverflow questions actually runs, I'm new here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work.

```
which(example$gender == "F" & example$wage == 2100 & example$age == 24)
```

Comment: @Luc If you want to avoid using `example$`multiple times you can use `with(example, which(gender == "F" & wage == 2100 & age == 24))` instead

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector `v` to be looped up

```
v <- data.frame(gender = 'F',wage = 2100,age = 24)
```

maybe you can try `match` like below

```
r <- match(data.frame(t(v),stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
           data.frame(t(example),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

such that

```
> r
[1] 2
```